# Not allowed to use else, don't see how i need to do it with this problem

Tags: c#

Entry level of c# (REALLY).

Today I got the problem to create a console app that allows someone to enter their surname, name and age. If they are under 18 they should be classified as "Youth", if they are 18 or above they are adults. The only catch is it should be done with very little knowledge and A BASIC understanding of if usage. AND using else is forbidden.

The code I came up with:

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Vul uw voornaam, familienaam en leeftijd in.");
    
    string voorNaam = Console.ReadLine();
    string familieNaam = Console.ReadLine();
    int leeftijd = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    
    string groepJeugd = "Jeugd";
    string groepVolwassen = "Volwassen";
    
    if (leeftijd < 18)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{voorNaam} {familieNaam}: {groepJeugd}");
    }
    else if (leeftijd >= 18) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{voorNaam} {familieNaam}: {groepVolwassen}");
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Small note, I don't know if it's correct to use "else if" If its not allowed to use else, I've thought about using switch, but since the lesson was about if, else etc... I dont think its correct to use it here.

Comment: Just take out the `else`. `leeftijd` can't both be less than and greater or equal to 18.

Comment: `if(! condition)`

Comment: Or, more simple, initialize it to one and swap it for the other condition. One variable, not two. `string group = "Jeugd"; if (leeftijd >= 18) { group = "Volwassen" }`

Comment: you should only use `if(leeftijd < 18)` , because when the if condition is not met, it will just continue without  executing the code inside. you can also use a `!` to say for example "if they are  not under 18" like this `if(!leeftijd < 18)`

Comment: Or `string group = (leeftijd < 18) ? groepJeugd : groepVolwassen; Console.WriteLine($"{voorNaam} {familieNaam}: {group}");`

Answer (score 3):

Set a default value of adult and override if under 18.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Vul uw voornaam, familienaam en leeftijd in.");

        string voorNaam = Console.ReadLine();
        string familieNaam = Console.ReadLine();
        int leeftijd = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        string group = "Volwassen";

        if(leeftijd < 18) 
        {
            group = "Jeugd";
        }

        Console.WriteLine($"{voorNaam} {familieNaam}: {group}");
       
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: So if I'm correct, this way if  

if (leeftijd < 18) 
it wil use group = "Jeugd" 
otherwise it will use "Volwassen"

I'm only a bit confused about the if not having { } to contain the code, why is that?

Comment: I added the { } so you don't get confused ;) but in C# if you only need a one-line statement after the if statement you can leave out the { } to make the code more compact. Some like it, some don't.

Answer (score 1):

Hope using `return` isn't forbidden

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Vul uw voornaam, familienaam en leeftijd in.");

           string voorNaam = Console.ReadLine();
           string familieNaam = Console.ReadLine();
           int leeftijd = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

           string groepJeugd = "Jeugd";
           string groepVolwassen = "Volwassen";

            if (leeftijd < 18)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{voorNaam} {familieNaam}: {groepJeugd}");
                Console.ReadLine();
                return;
            }
            Console.WriteLine($"{voorNaam} {familieNaam}: {groepVolwassen}");

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

1st way

```
var output=string.Empty;

if (leeftijd < 18) output= $"{voorNaam} {familieNaam}: {groepJeugd}";
if (leeftijd >= 18) output= $"{voorNaam} {familieNaam}: {groepVolwassen}";

Console.WriteLine(output);
```

2nd way, doesn't use else, but not sure if it allowed

```
var output = leeftijd < 18 ? $"{voorNaam} {familieNaam}: {groepJeugd}":
        $"{voorNaam} {familieNaam}: {groepVolwassen}";

Console.WriteLine(output);
```

Comment: Conditional expressions need to produce a value, pure statements (`Console.WriteLine`) are not allowed in this case

Comment: @vc74 Thanks. I updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

If you use `if` instead of the `else if`, it'll work too.
So there'll be 2 if conditions in your code.

```
if (leeftijd < 18)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{voorNaam} {familieNaam}: {groepJeugd}");
}
if (leeftijd >= 18)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{voorNaam} {familieNaam}: {groepVolwassen}");
}
```

Another way:

You can return once you get the first condition true.

In this case, you won't need another condition.

```
if (leeftijd < 18)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{voorNaam} {familieNaam}: {groepJeugd}");
    return ;
}

Console.WriteLine($"{voorNaam} {familieNaam}: {groepVolwassen}");
```

Answer (score 0):

hello i used this `?:` operator to do this and got true or false

```
(leeftijd >= 18 ? groepVolwassen : groepJeugd)
    /* if "leeftijd" is >= 18 put "groepVolwassen" and else with : put "groepJeugd" */
```

---

and its finally

```
Console.WriteLine($"{voorNaam} {familieNaam}: {(leeftijd >= 18 ? groepVolwassen : groepJeugd)}");
```

i hope you it help you if u want dont use else

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a trick question, there is technically no other option with such simple code, the compiler makes this choice for you. However, you can obfuscate it in several ways.

- `if / else`
- `if / else if` <- `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`
- `if return`
- `?:` operator <- if / else anyway
- `switch`
- `while loop return` <- if you want to get ***really*** weird

<sub>***Note** : You could possibly use an exception to branch, by causing any number of weird situations like divide by 0 exceptions, however I have left that absurdity out*</sub>

---

**if / else**

```
if (leeftijd < 18)
   Console.WriteLine($"{voorNaam} {familieNaam}: {groepJeugd}");
else 
   Console.WriteLine($"{voorNaam} {familieNaam}: {groepVolwassen}");
Console.ReadLine();
```

**if return**

```
if (leeftijd < 18)
{
   Console.WriteLine($"{voorNaam} {familieNaam}: {groepJeugd}");
   Console.ReadLine();
   return;
}
Console.WriteLine($"{voorNaam} {familieNaam}: {groepVolwassen}");

Console.ReadLine();
```

**Conditional Operator**

```
Console.WriteLine(
   leeftijd < 18 
      ? $"{voorNaam} {familieNaam}: {groepJeugd}" 
      : $"{voorNaam} {familieNaam}: {groepVolwassen}");
Console.ReadLine();
```

**switch**

```
switch (leeftijd)
{
   case < 18:
      Console.WriteLine($"{voorNaam} {familieNaam}: {groepJeugd}");
      break;
   case >= 18:
      Console.WriteLine($"{voorNaam} {familieNaam}: {groepVolwassen}");
      break;
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

**while loop return**

```
while (leeftijd < 18)
{
   Console.WriteLine($"{voorNaam} {familieNaam}: {groepJeugd}");
   Console.ReadLine();
   return;
}

Console.WriteLine($"{voorNaam} {familieNaam}: {groepVolwassen}");
Console.ReadLine();
```

## However

In all cases (except for the exception), the compiler will convert such simple cases to something like the following anyway

```
if (num < 18)
{
   ...
   Console.WriteLine(..);
   Console.ReadLine();
}
else
{
   ...
   Console.WriteLine(..);
   Console.ReadLine();
}
```

The short story, is the compiler only has a bunch of comparative operators no matter how you branch, it does have a switching type instruction, though in such a simple case it compiles it to an `if` anyway :/

- `Beq` - Branch on equal
- `Bne` - Branch on not equal
- `Bge` - Branch on greater than or equal
- `Bgt` - Branch on greater than
- `Ble` - Branch on less than or equal
- `Blt` - Branch on less than